# Filter each value, copy and paste each table into new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use vba code in order to choose each value in the table orderly and copy them into new sheet. As it is shown in the picture there is a table and in the column F we have 2 different values(it might be more than 2). What I need is when I run the macro it will select first value then will copy the table into new sheet (name of the sheet will be based on the value in the column F-for example 0.55) then will come back and select second value and do the same. we might have more than 6-7 values, so I don't know how to make a loop to do it automatically for all values. I need to add this process at the end of that code block. Becaue that codes doing something different and at the result I get that table.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim q As Workbook




'## Open all workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\barkod.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\csv.csv")
Set q = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\campaign.xlsx")


'## Clear the workbook first:
Windows("csv.csv").Activate
y.Sheets("csv").Range("A:M").Clear


'## Insert the column in the barkod file:
Windows("barkod.xlsx").Activate
x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F1").EntireColumn.Insert

'## Insert the column header in the barkod file:
x.Sheets("barkod").Range("E1").Offset(0, 1).Value = "Discounts"

'## make the vlookup in barkod file:
With x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], [campaign.xlsx]Sheet1!C[-5]:C[-4], 2, 0)"
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Offset(, -1).EntireColumn))
End With


'## deselect the #N/A:
Windows("barkod.xlsx").Activate
x.Sheets("barkod").Range(Sheets("barkod").Range("A1:F1"), Sheets("barkod").Range("A1:F1").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A:F").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"


'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("barkod").Range(Sheets("barkod").Range("A1:F1"), Sheets("barkod").Range("A1:F1").End(xlDown)).Copy


'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("csv").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: So you want to go through the unique items in column F and create a new sheet filter the values and name it after the F item?

Comment: Yes I want to go through the unique items in F column and create a new sheet for each unique item by filtering one by one automatically. so let's say we have 2 value in column F: 0.55 and 0.4. So we will have 2 sheet namely 0.4 and 0.55 and in that sheets we will have filtered values table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure should do what you want so you could give it a meaningful name and call it at the end of your existing code. It creates a list of unique items in F using advanced filter and then loops through each using AutoFilter to create the new sheet.

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim r As Range, r2 As Range, ws As Worksheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")   'change to suit
    Sheets.Add().Name = "Temp"
    .Range("F1", .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Temp").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
    Set r2 = Sheets("Temp").Range("A2", Sheets("Temp").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
     For Each r In r2
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=r
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy ws.Range("A1")
        ws.Name = r
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=6
    Next r
    Sheets("Temp").Delete
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it was exactly what I need. I really appreciate !